# Approaches to use Repositories (w/ StructureMap) with AutoMapper?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, inversion-of-control, structuremap, automapper

Any idea how I can tell AutoMapper to resolve a TypeConverter constructor argument using StructureMap?

ie. We have this:

```
    private class StringIdToContentProviderConverter : TypeConverter<string, ContentProvider> {
        private readonly IContentProviderRepository _repository;

        public StringIdToContentProviderConverter(IContentProviderRepository repository) {
            _repository = repository;
        }

        public StringIdToContentProviderConverter() {
            _repository = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IContentProviderRepository>();
        }

        protected override ContentProvider ConvertCore(string contentProviderId) {
            return _repository.Get(new Guid(contentProviderId));
        }
    }
```

And in the AutoMap registration:

```
        Mapper.CreateMap<Guid, ContentProvider>().ConvertUsing<GuidToContentProviderConverter>();
```

However, I don't like the idea of hardwiring an ObjectFactory.GetInstance in my constructor for the converter. Any ideas how I can tell AutoMapper how to resolve my IContentProviderRepository?

Or ideas to other approaches for using Automapper to hydrate domain objects from viewmodel ID's using a repository?

Comment: Shouldn't automapper just map?

Comment: How do you map an Guid coming back from your view to a full blown domain object?

Comment: That is not mapping, that is data-access.

Comment: Ok agreed. What would you suggest instead?

Comment: Depends on how you use it? How do you use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use this (in one of our Bootstrapper tasks)...

```
        private IContainer _container; //Structuremap container

        Mapper.Initialize(map =>
        {
            map.ConstructServicesUsing(_container.GetInstance);
            map.AddProfile<MyMapperProfile>();
        }
```

Comment: Hi Arnis, not sure what you mean? 'MyMapperProfile' just extends the Profile class as supplied by AutoMapper. We are telling AutoMapper what IoC container we are using.

Answer (score 1):

The `ConstructUsing` method seems to have an overload that accepts a `Func<T1,T2>` . In there you could access your container.

**EDIT:**
Convert also knows such an overload such that you could do:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<A, B>().ConvertUsing(i=> c.With(i).GetInstance<B>());
```

Where c is your container

Comment: Sorry, ContructUsing should be ConvertUsing

Comment: Thanks, this also works, but I think the accepted solution is cleaner